# Split string after and before first needle. Optimal version

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I have string, string may contained 0 or more colon  ":"

I need split this string and obtain 2 variables:

1) `$before` = string before first colon
2) `$after` = string after  first colon

if string not contain colon,  `$before` and `$after` must be empty strings

that is, from `aa:ss:dd:44`

`$before = aa` and `$after = ss:dd:44`

I have 2 idea, how do this:

1)

```
    $str = "aa:ss:dd:44";

    $before = mb_strstr($str, ":", TRUE, "utf-8");

    $after = mb_substr( mb_strstr($str, ":", FALSE, "utf-8"), 1, mb_strlen($str, "utf-8") , "utf-8" );
```

2)

```
    $str = "aa:ss:dd:44";

    preg_match_all("#(^[^:]*):(.*)#u", $str, $matches);

    if (isset($matches[1][0])) {
        $before = $matches[1][0];
    }
    else {
        $before = "";
    }


    if (isset($matches[2][0])) {
        $after = $matches[2][0];
    }
    else {
        $after = "";
    }
```

But I think both are not optimal things, you have some better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode`:

```
$result = explode(':', $string, 2);
if (count($result) == 1) {
    $before = $after = "";
}
else {
    $before = $result[0];
    $after = $result[1];
}
```

Comment: Very nice `$limit` argument for explode(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should work.

```
list($before, $after) = array_pad(explode(':', $string, 2), 2, '');
```

Comment: This will issue a notice if there is no `:` in the string

Comment: @Rob it's the `list`/`explode` combination that issues the notice

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
$before = $after = '';
$str = "aa:ss:dd:44";
$ar_fields = explode( ":", $str, 2 );
if ( count( $ar_fields ) > 1 ) {
    $before = $ar_fields[0];
    $after = $ar_fields[1];
}
```